# Linux : Standard way for running and closing apps in Terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I am new to Linux and open apps in Terminal by their name. How can I close these apps standardly?

> *user@localhost:~$ vlc
> VLC media player 3.0.9.2 Vetinari (revision 3.0.9.2-0-gd4c1aefe4d) [000056025a447670] main libvlc: Running vlc with the default interface. Use 'cvlc' to use vlc without interface.
> [000056025a4e2700] main playlist: playlist is empty*

Comment: What desktop environment? Nothing wrong with starting from a command line -- but most desktops provide a menu. And since you are running in a desktop environment, why not just use the window control or exit? Most applications, even without window decoration or menu provided control by a Rt-click context menu. Do none of those apply to your situation?

Answer (score 0):

[Press Ctrl+C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Control-C) to interrupt the process.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. what is different between Ctrl+C and Ctrl+\ or Ctrl+4 ?

Answer (score 0):

For those command line programs that take input from standard input and write output into standard output, there is a convention that the so called EOF (which means End Of File) indicates the job of the program is finished. UNIX people call these commands **filters**.

You can create such a EOF manually by `Ctrl+D` in most UNIX environment.

For example, you can enter the Python CLI by typing its name in Bash shell, then after you have finished your task, you can type `Ctrl+D` to exit Python CLI gracefully.